# Network adapters for Sony Vaio VPCEH2D0E

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, sony-vaio

I have been painstakingly searching the web for answers with no result!!

I rebooted and reinstalled windows 7 on my pc. I am running windows 7 ultimate 32-bit on a Sony Vaio intel pentium CPU B950.

It all works fine apart from the the wireless or network adapters drivers!

I managed to install Realtek PCIe GEB network adapter driver and still not success in the computer reconginizing any wifi connection

On device manager 'other devices' tabs: network controller, pci device, pci simple comuunications controller, sm bus controller and unknow device they're all have a ! sign next to it which I'm assuming they're not installed.

Now to the question: Is the Realtek PCIe GEB the right driver for my computer? If so how can i resolve the other devices to work? if not where could I find the driver for this??!!

Please I'm going mad, thank you for all your help and support

---

On Device Manager, I can't find a tab that says 'WI-FI' network. On the 'network controller' tab I follow the steps you told me and this is what It says:

PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002B&SUBSYS_E037105B&REV_01

PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002B&SUBSYS_E037105B

PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002B&CC_02800

PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002B&CC_0280

thanks

Comment: The official [Sony support page](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/content/cnt-dwnl/VPCEH2D0E/list#os1) provides a Wi-Fi driver. Did you try installing it?

Comment: Cheers and tried that one but Im running 32-bit and can only find 64-bit drivers on sony official support. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Open the Device Manager, locate the Wi-Fi network card and open the **Properties** dialog. Switch to the **Details** tab, and check what's the hardware ID. Then post here the value.

Comment: Click on [this](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SVE14112FXP&LOC=3#/downloadTab) link. Double check for your model number on the top-right of the page. Good luck